# Samsung s3 makes "plugged in" noises while charging

Tags: charging, audio, samsung

I have recently bought a third party USB cable. I am still using the original wall adapter that I got. Now, I noticed that while charging, it sometimes makes the "plugged in" sound as if I had just plugged in the cable onto my phone. It does that several times randomly and I thought I just hadn't plugged it in correctly, but I've checked and that is not the case? Is there a problem with NON-Samsung USB cables (if such thing even exists)? The phone does charge, it never stops charging, but it makes that notification sound as if I had just put it to charge, even though it has been charging for some time already.

Comment: Seems like you have an intermittent connection. Have you checked the quality of all related wires and plugs?

Comment: I agree with @aureljared. Sometimes cables (third-party or not) just wear out, or have defects that cause an intermittent connection. There's no difference between Samsung and non-Samsung cables.

Comment: I had this, I bought a cheap micro USB cable, it worked fine. Tried the old cable again and now it also works fine :| Was very odd. It kept "charging" then "not charging" in a loop amd making the beep noise. Easiest thing to do is try a different cable (they're all the same)

Comment: This is odd. I have this external battery pack and I use the same cable to charge my phone and... guess what? It stopped making that noise. It could be the wall adapter after all...